Issue with JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<IEnumerable<dynamic>>>(Reportdata[0]) returning empty arrays for values
In C# I have a function that returns an IEnumerable, which contains an array of objects in a specific format. The returned data looks like this:
[[{"id":1,"Name":"joy","School":"BMH","Class":"tenth"}],
 [{"order":1,"Name":"product1","DisplayName":"watch1","Columntype":"text1"}],
 [{"order":2,"Name":"product2","DisplayName":"watch2","Columntype":"text2"}]]

When I try to deserialize this data using the following code:
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<IEnumerable<dynamic>>>(Reportdata[0])

I am getting the following output:
[
    [
        {
            "id": [],
            "Name": [],
            "School": [],
            "Class": []
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "Order": [],
            "Name": [],
            "DisplayName": [],
            "ColumnType": []
        }
    ]
]

However, I was expecting the following output:
[
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "Name": "joy",
            "School": "BMH",
            "Class": "tenth"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "Order": 1,
            "Name": "product1",
            "DisplayName": "watch1",
            "ColumnType": "text1"
        },
        {
            "Order": 2,
            "Name": "product2",
            "DisplayName": "watch2",
            "ColumnType": "text2"
        }
    ]
]

It seems like the keys are being returned correctly, but the values are showing up as empty arrays.
What am I missing or doing wrong in my deserialization process? Is there something specific I need to adjust with the JsonConvert.DeserializeObject call to correctly map the values to the properties?

Do you not have a DTO for representing your object? If you did the specified generic types when deserializing then becomes: JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<IEnumerable<MyDto>>>. Currently you're using the non generic version of IEnumerable so the serializer probably doesn't know what do with your JSON data.

No, I don't have a DTO to represent the object, but the value type is dynamic, coming from DynamoDB.

Try creating a class to represent your JSON object and see what happens.

How are you viewing the output? And which JSON library? I've just tried in LINQPad with Newtonsoft.Json, and the resulting JObject values have the expected property values.

To meet your requirement,you need add NewtonSoft support:
1.Install the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson package.
2.Update Startup.ConfigureServices(.NET Core framework before .NET 5) or Program.cs(framework beyond .NET 5) to call AddNewtonsoftJson.
Before .NET 5
services.AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson();

.NET 6,7,8
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();

